# Two lists - removing elements (difference)

Tags: python, set-difference

I have this class

```
class Accounts:
    def __init__(self, id, name, date):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.date = date
```

and two lists of this classes

```
accounts = []
expired_accounts = []
```

I want to delete elements which are in `expired_accounts` from `accounts` `(expired_accounts - accounts)`

Appending elements

```
accounts.append(Accounts(id=690000, name="test", date=123456))
print(len(accounts))
expired_accounts(Accounts(id=690000, name="test", date=123456))
print(len(expired_accounts))
```

Output:

```
1
1
```

Now trying to remove elements

```
test = [x for x in accounts if x not in set(expired_accounts)]
print(len(test))
```

Output (expecting 0):

```
1
```

I tried different solutions from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4211209/remove-all-the-elements-that-occur-in-one-list-from-another), but neither of them work for my case and I don't know why. Could someone help me, where is the problem?

Comment: Use sets to store objects. Then you can do set1.difference(set2)

Comment: Add the `__eq__` method to be able to compare class instances, needed for the `if x not in ...` check.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to check if two object contain the same values in each of their variables in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6423814/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-two-object-contain-the-same-values-in-each-of-their-v)